# Что нужно сделать с приложением перед добавлением в google play?

Tags: android, google-play

У меня уже практически готовая версия приложения (осталось доделать маленькие штрихи), даже зарегистрировался как разработчик, но я не знаю точно, что надо сделать с приложением. Читал как-то статью об этом, но потерял её. Там говорилось,что нужно что-то в эклипсе сделать, потом в ProGuard и т.п. Подскажите, пожалуйста,что нужно сделать по пунктам или дайте ссылку на подробную статью. Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Сгенерировать сертификат.
2. Если приложение paid, то озаботиться защитой через [License Verification Library](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview.html).
3. [Подписать](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) сгенерированным сертификатом.
4. ProGuard необязательно.
5. Выставить в [Google Play](http://play.google.com/publish).

Чеклист, что надо сделать, [здесь](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html), и немного [устаревшая статья](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/publish.php).